# meteor users collection resubscribes every 10 seconds

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an app that when running in developer mod (meteor run) works great I get the subscribe to the users collection, then the app continues on normally.  But when I push the code to the live server, I get an issue where the users collection is updating every 10 seconds and as a result the users collection is resubscribed every 10 seconds on the client.

Any thoughts to would could be causing the updating?

- Meteor 1.2
- NodeJS 0.10.40
- Mongo 2.6.11
- uBuntu 14.04 Server

On Server

```
Meteor.publish("usersAllFields", function()
{
  var self=this;
  this.autorun(function(computation)
  {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: self.userId}); // self only, all fields
  });
});
```

on Client

```
Router.configure(
{
  layoutTemplate: 'layout', // default template
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',   // template when loading
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound', // template when 404 (not found)
  waitOn: doSubscribe
});

doSubscribe = function()
{ 
    console.log('doSubscribe() waitOn');

    return Meteor.user()
    && Meteor.subscribe('usersAllFields'); // self only, unless admin
};
```

Comment: probably your subscribe is in a block of reactive code that re-runs for some reason. No way to answer this without seeing your code

Comment: I just added a bit of code... sorry

Comment: wrapping your publication in this.autorun is probably unnecessary in this instance since you are just publishing a single cursor (autoruns typically used when trying to simulate joins). not sure if that would cause the problem you describe however.